# ANTLR parse multiple files to produce one AST

Tags: antlr

How do i parse multiple source file and end up with just one AST to perform analysis and code generation from? Typically, I find example usage of ANTLR in the form of

```
public void process(String source) 
{
    ANTLRStringStream Input = new ANTLRStringStream(input);
    TLexer lex = new TLexer(Input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
    TParser parser = new TParser(tokens);
    var tree = parser.parse().Tree; 
}
```

but neither the lexer nor the parser seems to be able to take additional files. Am I supposed to create a lexer and parser pr. inputfile and use tree.Add() to add trees from the other files to the tree of the first file?

Comment: What about reading all files into a string, and parsing that string?

Comment: Alas, then I have no way of returning sensible error messages with filename and linenumbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three ways you could do this:

1. Use Bart's suggestion and combine the files into a single buffer. This would require adding a lexer rule that implements identical functionality to the C++ #line directive.
2. Combine the trees returned by the parser rule.
3. Use multiple input streams with a single lexer. This can be done by using code similar to that which handles [include files](http://web.archive.org/web/20130120150251/http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=557057) by pushing all buffers onto the stack before lexing.

The second option would probably be the easiest. I don't use the Java target so I can't give code details, which is required for all of these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I think this close to what you are after. I've hard-coded two files to process but you can process as many as needed by creating a loop. At the step `// create new parent node and merge trees here into fulltree` see Bart's answer [on duplicating a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781019/antlr-duplicate-a-tree). It has the steps to create a parent node and attach children to it (sorry but I've not done this and didn't have time to integrate his code and test).

```java
public class OneASTfromTwoFiles {
    public String source1 = "file1.txt";
    public String source2 = "file2.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    CommonTree fulltree;
    {
        CommonTree nodes1 = process(source1);
        CommonTree nodes2 = process(source2);
        // create new parent node and merge trees here into fulltree
        CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream(fulltree); //create node stream
        treeEval walker = new treeEval(fulltree);
        walker.startRule(); //walk the combined tree
    }

    public CommonTree process(String source)
    {
        CharStream afs = null;
        // read file; exit if error
        try { 
            afs = new ANTLRFileStream(source);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        TLexer lex = new TLexer(afs);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
        TParser parser = new TParser(tokens);
        //note startRule is the name of the first rule in your parser grammar
        TParser.startRule_return r = parser.startRule(); //parse this file
        CommonTree ast = (CommonTree)r.getTree(); //create AST from parse of this file
        return ast; //and return it
    }
}
```